# Given my heading and bearing to another object how can I turn to face it?

Tags: algorithm, math

I have my `heading` in degrees and the `bearing` to another guy in degrees. I also know my position and his position. How do I go about turning towards him?

- `heading` - Degrees from North clockwise that I'm facing
- `bearing` - Degrees from North clockwise to the other guy

I also have `myPosX`, `myPosY`, `badPosX` and `badPosY` if they would be useful.

I've tried the following bit of code, and it kinda works.

```
local x = heading - bearing
if (x < 0) then
  TurnRight()
else
  TurnLeft()
end
```

The issue is if the when the bearing changes from my right to my left then I basically turn the whole way around clockwise rather than still tracking counterclockwise.

I'm not sure how to go about getting the tracking to keep turning smoothly when the bearing goes from left (say 120deg) to right (say 80deg) while my heading is between (say 100deg).

`TurnRight()` will `+1` to my `heading` and `TurnLeft()` will `-1` to my `heading`.

Comment: What do you mean by "bearing to another guy"? Isn't that the angle to the other guy? If so, don't you simply want to add that (modulo 360) to the heading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `heading` and `bearing` are in the range [0, 360), you can write:

```
local x = (360 + heading - bearing) % 360
if (x > 180) then
  TurnRight()
else
  TurnLeft()
end
```